# Toggle Plotly shapes by clicking on them (Python)

Tags: python, plotly, shapes

I have two large collections of squares to plot using Plotly in Python.  There are enough squares (each represented by trace of form `go.Scatter(.., fill="toself")` in each group that it would be impractical to give an entry to each one, in the legend.  However, the squares do overlap, so it would be ideal to be able to

- click a square to toggle it off
- create a legend entry for each group, so that each set can be toggled on or off as a group

I'm aware of interactive Plotly widgets and have tried some exercises for toggling individuals points, but this seems much more complex.